# Improve code result speed by multiprocessing

Tags: performance, multiprocessing

I'm self study of Python and it's my first code.
I'm working for analyze logs from the servers. Usually I need analyze full day logs. I created script (this is example, simple logic) just for check speed. If I use normal coding the duration of analyzing 20mil rows about 12-13 minutes. I need 200mil rows by 5 min.
What I tried:

1. Use multiprocessing (met issue with share memory, think that fix it). But as the result - 300K rows = 20 sec and no matter how many processes. (PS: Also need control processors count in advance)
2. Use threading (I found that it's not give any speed, 300K rows = 2 sec. But normal code same, 300K = 2 sec)
3. Use asyncio (I think that script is slow because need reads many files). Result same as threading - 300K = 2 sec.
   Finally I think that all three my script incorrect and didn't work correctly.

PS: I try to avoid use specific python modules (like pandas) because in this case it will be more difficult to execute on different servers. Better to use common lib.

Please help to check 1st - multiprocessing.

```py
import csv
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Value, Manager

file = {"hcs.log", "hcs1.log", "hcs2.log", "hcs3.log"}

def argument(m, a, n):
     proc_num = os.getpid()
     a_temp_m = a["vod_miss"]
     a_temp_h = a["vod_hit"]
     with open(os.getcwd() + '/' + m, newline='') as hcs_1:
         hcs_2 = csv.reader(hcs_1, delimiter=' ')
         for j in hcs_2:
             if j[3].find('MISS') != -1:
                 a_temp_m[n] = a_temp_m[n] + 1
             elif j[3].find('HIT') != -1:
                 a_temp_h[n] = a_temp_h[n] + 1
     a["vod_miss"][n] = a_temp_m[n]
     a["vod_hit"][n] = a_temp_h[n]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    procs = []
    manager = Manager()
    vod_live_cuts = manager.dict()
    i = "vod_hit"
    ii = "vod_miss"
    cpu = 1
    n = 1
    vod_live_cuts[i] = manager.list([0] * cpu)
    vod_live_cuts[ii] = manager.list([0] * cpu)
    for m in file:
        proc = Process(target=argument, args=(m, vod_live_cuts, (n-1)))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()
        if n >= cpu:
            n = 1
            proc.join()
        else:
            n += 1
    [proc.join() for proc in procs]
    [proc.close() for proc in procs]
```

I'm expect, each file by def argument will be processed by independent process and finally all results will be saved in dict vod_live_cuts. For each process I added independent list in dict. I think it will help cross operation for use this parameter. But maybe it's wrong way :(

Comment: how big is 1 file in MBs ? how much time does it take to process 1 file without multiprocessing ? and can you split 1 file into many files ? also what hardware is the files on ? like HDD SSD ? and number of cores on machine ?

Comment: to put things into perspective , you cannot really process things faster than your HDD/SSD speed, so if that thing is running at 50 MB/sec, you cannot parse more than 3 GBs/minute, which means you can only process at best around 15 GBs in those 5 minutes, so if you have 100 GBs of logs, you need at least 35 minutes to process these even if you rewrote your entire codebase in C.

Comment: one file about 200Mb. One file about 300-500K row and time about 13-15 sec. For one day logs (and I need analyze full day) about 1200-1500 files. I don't want to split. better use one CPU for one file. HW - rack server with 8CPU. HDD - not SSD, SATA.

Comment: I have checked atop during run the script (normal one, without multiprocessing). Inside I have two def, one for just open each file and count rows. During this function - HDD busy on 100%. But for second function - counting inside of each file (similar what I post here) the HDD busy just 10-25%. It means I still can improve speed. :) In any case, what could be wrong in my code for multiprocessing? Why it's work slower than normal one? Any mistake?

Comment: def total_r():
    global total_rows
    for z in file:  # Counting how many rows totaly we will have for this process#
        total_rows = total_rows + sum(1 for file in open(os.getcwd() + '\/' + z, 'r'))
This code ocupate HDD on 100% but counting 20Mil rows by 10second

Comment: In any case. Looks like in my situation HDD not a bottleneck. (200Mb each file, 60 files, 20Mil rows, script duration 13 minutes - HDD I/O used about 10%. One CPU - 100% but I have 7 more). I hope if I can use 4 CPU it will be 4 times faster.

Comment: this is test result of code upper    `Duration: 0:01:09.430188 - 1 CPU / 4 logs
                                                      Duration: 0:01:08.880098 - 2 CPU / 4 logs
                                                      Duration: 0:01:14.003960 - 3 CPU / 4 logs
                                                      Duration: 0:01:18.146740 - 4 CPU / 4 logs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using IPC is costly, so only use "shared objects" for saving the final result, not for intermediate results while parsing the file.

limiting the number of processes is done by using a `multiprocessing.Pool`, the following code uses it to reach the max hard-disk speed, you only need to post-process the results.

you can only parse data as fast as your HDD can read it (typically 30-80 MB/s), so if you need to improve the performance further you should use SSD or RAID0 for higher disk speed, you cannot get much faster than this without changing your hardware.

```py
import csv
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Value, Manager, Pool

file = {"hcs.log", "hcs1.log", "hcs2.log", "hcs3.log"}

def argument(m, a):
     proc_num = os.getpid()
     a_temp_m_n = 0  # make it local to process
     a_temp_h_n = 0  # as shared lists use IPC
     with open(os.getcwd() + '/' + m, newline='') as hcs_1:
         hcs_2 = csv.reader(hcs_1, delimiter=' ')
         for j in hcs_2:
             if j[3].find('MISS') != -1:
                 a_temp_m_n = a_temp_m_n + 1
             elif j[3].find('HIT') != -1:
                 a_temp_h_n = a_temp_h_n + 1
     a["vod_miss"].append(a_temp_m_n)
     a["vod_hit"].append(a_temp_h_n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    vod_live_cuts = manager.dict()
    i = "vod_hit"
    ii = "vod_miss"
    cpu = 1
    vod_live_cuts[i] = manager.list()
    vod_live_cuts[ii] = manager.list()
    with Pool(cpu) as pool:
        tasks = []
        for m in file:
            task = pool.apply_async(argument, args=(m, vod_live_cuts))
            tasks.append(task)
        for task in tasks:
            task.get()
    print(list(vod_live_cuts[i]))
    print(list(vod_live_cuts[ii]))
```

Comment: `Duration: 0:00:05.357189 - 1 CPU / 4 logs
Duration: 0:00:03.558837 - 2 CPU / 4 logs
Duration: 0:00:02.889532 - 3 CPU / 4 logs
Duration: 0:00:02.786059 - 4 CPU / 4 logs`

Comment: Thank you for help.. It's work now. For HDD, yes you are right. I use Raid 10 and at least 3-4 parallel processed could work well.

Comment: @DmitriyN if this solves your question, you should accept the answer as the correct answer (the true sign to the left of the answer)

Comment: One additional question. By a[x].append(b) command I added new value to list. If I will have 1000 files I will have list with 1000 elements. Is it possible in multiprocessing code to have one value what will multiply each time? For example: a[x] = a[x] + b? Or it's exactly what you wrote about IPC costly?

Comment: @DmitriyN problem is not only about it being costly, this is a race condition, and you will run into bugs, better sum the results in the main process after everything is done, or you'll have to use multiprocessing lock to prevent race conditions, while `append` is guaranteed by python to be safe and will not result in race conditions, however `a[x] = a[x] + b` will result in a race condition if it is done in another process.